# How to internationalize Grails Geb tests

Tags: grails, functional-testing, geb

My web-app utilizes Geb for functional testing.

It is a non-english application, all page messages being received from i18n message bundle.

How to make Geb work with internationalized messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Grails RemoteControl plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-control) allows remote access to a running Grails application. In a functional test setting it can be used to read and change configuration settings, access the application context including the message source, … .

The code below is added to a common base class for all our Geb specifications/tests that can be used in an individual test to retrieve an internationalized message:

```
class BaseTest/Spec {

    RemoteControl remoteControl = new RemoteControl()

    String msg(String msgKey, args = null, locale = defaultLocale) {
        if (args != null) {
            args = args as Object[]
        }
        return remoteControl.exec {
            ctx.messageSource.getMessage(msgKey, args, locale)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All my page classes extend from base class: ScaffoldPage

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;        

import geb.Page        

class ScaffoldPage extends Page {        
    static content = {          
        resourceBundle {
            ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream('./grails-app/i18n/messages_ru.properties'), "UTF-8"))         
            bundle        
        }        
    }        
}
```

Then, at a certain page, I use a construction like this:

```
class CreatePayeePage extends ScaffoldPage {
    static at = { 
        title == resourceBundle.getString('payee.title.create.label')
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance......where is defined the method getString of resourceBundle?

Comment: @Mauro it's in java.util.ResourceBundle.

Comment: resourceBundle that gets used within your tests is in turn ScaffoldPage/content/resourceBundle  <-- this is actually a closure to initiate different script variables. Read on more with official Geb examples, there are plenty of them.